# Fazer div filha ter mesmo tamanho de pai fixo

Tags: javascript, css, layout-responsivo

Estou montando um layout responsivo...

Meu "menucontainer" é fixo...

Então a largura dele não acompanha o tamanho da interface do site...

Por esse motivo quando o zoom aumenta ele vai ficando e não pega fluidez.

Então, se eu conseguisse fazer com que a cada `window.resize` o tamanho do "menucontainer" se igualasse ao da interface do layout, eu forçaria uma fluidez.

Então eu fiz assim (não funciona):

```
function resizee(){
        var box = document.querySelector('.boxinterface');
        var hcont = document.querySelector('.headercontainer');
        box.style.maxWidth = "1100px";
        setInterval(function(){
            hcont.style.width = box.style.width;
        },3000);
    }
window.addEventListener('resize',resizee,false);
resize();
```

Até consegui resolver esse problema com `media queries`, mas achei não ideal porque tem que definir varios `breakpoints`... ainda mais porque isso é uma mera questão de fluidez.

#### jsFiddle com o problema: http://jsfiddle.net/9p55xp6w/2/

Comment: Qual é o CSS desse `menucontainer`? está a usar `px`, `%` ou `em`?

Comment: Não é melhor trabalhar com `%` já que o site é responsivo?

Comment: @renan haha, pensamos o mesmo ao mesmo tempo :)

Comment: @Sergio Olho de coruja, fomos direto no `px` :P

Comment: pq não usa o bootstrap? (http://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: voce poderia usar o bootstrap tem varias derramentas prontas.

Comment: @Sergio ele está em `px` porque se por em `%` fica a maior bagunça.

Comment: @Sergio http://jsfiddle.net/9p55xp6w/2/

Comment: @ropbla9 isso pode ser feito só com CSS, usando o `width: inherit;` e defenindo uma `width` para a div pai (exemplo 80%), assim: http://jsfiddle.net/sq5zwd32/ - votei para reabrir e vou dar isso como resposta se achar que pode resolver o seu problema.

Comment: @Sergio é devia funcionar, mas aqui n ta funcionando. Quando coloco inherit o menucontainer fica da matedo do tamanho da interface

Comment: @ropbla9 e tem defenido o `width` do pai? não somente com `max-width`? se não dá tem de atualizar o jsFiddle ou postar a página completa para ver onde pode estar o problema.

Comment: @ropbla9 consegui pôr isto a funcionar?

Comment: @Sergio, o width sozinho funciona, o max-width não. Então o defini um breakpoint de min-width na ampliação outro pra deixar full canvas em certo momento da redução. Dessa forma o header fixo ta acompanhando a interface.

Answer (score 2):

Não tenho certeza se entendi corretamente o problema, mas você acredito que isso resolva o seu problema:

```
.boxinterface{
    max-width: 500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height: 600px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 1px rgba(51, 50, 50, 0.2);
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.headercontainer{
    position:fixed;
    margin-top:-3px;
    width: 81.2%;
    max-width: 410px;
    background-color:#f5f5f5;
    z-index:1;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9p55xp6w/4/

Answer (score 2):

Da forma que você está fazendo não funcionará mesmo pois a propriedade `fixed` tem o seu posicionamento calculado em relação a tela. Querer que a `div` filha se mostre fixa (visualmente) no topo da `div` pai não quer dizer que isto deve ser feito com `position:fixed`. [Nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38218/4808) há uma explicação sobre essas propriedades e seu comportamento de cada uma.

Ao invés de `fixed`, utilize a posição `absolute` na sua `div` filha. Já na `div` pai, use posição `relative`. Isso fará com que o posicionamento da filha seja calculada em relação ao pai e não à tela.

```css
.box-interface {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height: 600px;
    background: #ecf0f1
}

.box-interface > header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    height: 80px;
    background: #9b59b6
}
```

```html
<div class='box-interface'>
    <header>aa</header>
</div>
```