# Div ou imagem aparece apenas dentro de outra

Tags: jquery, html, css, html5, css3

gostaria de colocar uma div ou uma imagem ( de preferência div, se for possível ) dentro de outra, por exemplo, eu queria que a Div não aparecesse fora da outra, caso esteja ultrapassando ficar por tras.
 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No exemplo abaixo, mostra bem o que quero, a primeira imagem está por tras de Avaliação, só que por cima da parte preta,já a imagem de baixo, está por cima de avaliação e duo, mas gostaria que ficasse por baixo, ou melhor, que só aparece dentro de inner, a de avaliação apenas aparece a parte que está dentro do box.

Comment: Acho que essa pergunta tem o que você quer. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38215/quando-usar-position-absolute-ou-relative-em-css

Comment: Na verrdade não consegui achar, deixo position absolute e coloco z-index menor na imagem, porém mesmo assim ele sai de dentro da outra. :\

Comment: tente usar a propriedade overflow:hidden na imagem de cima

Comment: Consegui com essa propriedade, até alguém tinha colocado uma responta, mas sumiu kkk, mas ficou perfeito com o overflow.

Obrigado pessoal!

Comment: Publiquei uma resposta correta para não precisarem checar os comentários para uma resposta. Abraços

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nos css [inclua](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) `overflow:hidden` e `position:relative` na div mãe, e jogue com o posicionamento dos elementos (`left`, `top`, `right`, `bottom`). EX:

```css
    div {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .fita {
        width: 80px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .fita:nth-child(1) {
        left: -20px;
        top: -5px;
        transform:rotate(-45deg);
    }
    .fita:nth-child(2) {
        right: -20px;
        top: -5px;
        transform:rotate(45deg);
    }
    .fita:nth-child(3) {
        left: -20px;
        bottom: -5px;
        transform:rotate(45deg);
    }
    .fita:nth-child(4) {
        right: -20px;
        bottom: -5px;
        transform:rotate(-45deg);
    }
```

```html
<div>
    <img class="fita" src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/05/26/10/53/pink-784526_960_720.png">
    <img class="fita" src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/05/26/10/53/pink-784526_960_720.png">
    <img class="fita" src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/05/26/10/53/pink-784526_960_720.png">
    <img class="fita" src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/05/26/10/53/pink-784526_960_720.png">
    <img src="http://www.personal.psu.edu/jul229/mini.jpg">
</div>

<br>
<br>
imagens Reais:
<br>
<img src="http://www.personal.psu.edu/jul229/mini.jpg">
<br>
<img class="fita" src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/05/26/10/53/pink-784526_960_720.png">
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a propriedade `overflow:hidden`, que define o que acontece com o conteúdo da `div` se ele "transborda" o tamanho da `div`