# Com funciona a propriedade Position?

Tags: html, css, css3

Já li sobre a propriedade `position`, mas ainda não conseguir entender o proposito dela. Os valores `absolute` e `relative` não entraram na minha cabeça. Também queria saber quando eu devo utilizar essa propriedade.

Comment: Da uma lida nesse link se puder: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38215/quando-usar-position-absolute-ou-relative-em-css, talvez ajude.

Aliás, nela tem as respostas para a sua pergunta.

Answer (score 4):

Existem quatro valores para a propriedade `Position: Static, Relative, Fixed e Absolute`

**Static**

O position: static; não tem por base as propriedades `top, left, bottom ou right`, ele simplesmente fica no lugar onde você o colocou "estático" e acompanha no fluir normal da página.

**Relative**

O valor relative faz com que o elemento seja posicionado relativamente de acordo com o valor informado em `top, left, bottom ou right`.

Ex.: se você configurar um elemento assim:

```
position: relative;
left: 10;
```

Ele ficará na posição normal no fluir da página acrescentado +10px de distância da lateral esquerda.

**Fixed**

Um elemento configurado com `fixed`, ficará fixo na tela, não importando o quanto você desça a página para baixo. Quando você vê um site que tem um menu superior que fica sempre no topo, independente de você descer a barra de rolagem para baixo, provavelmente está marcado como `position: fixed;`.

**Absolute**

O elemento com position: absolute; fica posicionado relativamente ao elemento "superior" a ele (caso esteja dentro de um outro elemento), ou relativamente ao body (caso não esteja dentro de outro elemento). Se você o configurar assim:

```
position: absolute;
left: 10;
top: 20;
```

Ele se manterá na posição "10, 20", e diferente do fixed, quando você descer o scroll da tela, ele irá se mover, mantendo sempre a posição absoluta em relação ao elemento "superior".

Caso ele esteja dentro de uma outra div, a posição "10, 20" que citei antes, seria referente à ela.

Ex: se a div pai estiver na posição "20, 30", a div absoluta estaria na "20, 50".