# Duvidas com Position

Tags: html, css

Estou com uma dúvida em relação ao position do logo de um site que estou criando.

Estou aprendendo agora HTML e CSS, estou com algumas dúvidas uma delas seria essa do posicionamento do logo.

Essa imagem a seguir seria no Software DW, ela está cortada no final mas está na posição que gostaria que ficasse.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora quando simulo no Software com F12 ela fica assim :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código CSS e HTML :

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
font-family:Calibri;
font-size:30px;
line-height:36px;
color:rgb(255,255,255);
text-align:left;
}

#topo {
 background:url(../imagens/topo.png); 
 width:1024px;
 height:190px;
 border-bottom:none;
 margin:auto;
 
}

#logo {
 float : right;
 background: url(../imagens/logoc.png);
 width: 528px;
 height: 133px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 37px;
 left: 35px;
 
 
  
 
}

#fundoinicial {
 width:1024px;
 height:1080px;
 margin:10px auto 20px auto;
 background-image:url(../imagens/fundoof.png);
 
}
```

```html
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
body {
 background-image: url(../PLANILHAS%20CAIO/projeto/imagens/fundo.jpg);
}
</style>
</head>


<body>

 <div id ="logo"></div><!--div logo-->
 <div id ="topo"></div><!--div do topo-->
    <div id ="fundoinicial"></div><!--div fundo-->
      
    

        
    <div id="menu_conteiner"> <!--div menu-->
          <div id="menu">
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Pagina Inicial</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Areas de cobertura</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Serviços</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Quem somos</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Fale conosco</a></li>
             </ul>
     </div>                   
         
   
    
       
    
     
    
 
      
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tenho um ódio profundo pela falta de fidelidade do trabalho no Dreamweaver. Dica: abandona o quanto antes essa ferramenta.

Comment: Por enquanto estou usando essa ferramenta por encontrar alguns tutoriais , se poder me ajudar indicando livros ou videos eu ficaria muito grato !!

Comment: @CaioWesley aqui tem uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38215/quando-usar-position-absolute-ou-relative-em-css) sensacional sobre position.

Comment: @CaioWesley sobre sugestão de material é bem complicado, vai de cada um. Eu fui aprendendo no google mesmo debaixo da necessidade e com muito teste. Mas uma coisa que sempre fiz foi aprender diretamente no Notepad++ e com muito Inspect no Chrome.

Comment: Entendi @LeonFreire muito obrigado pela ajuda !!!

Comment: @CaioWesley Acho que se você checar como anda o seu site agora no Chrome e der um inspect, você conseguirá ter uma ideia boa de porque isso está acontecendo.